# pip install mechanize works fine; why permission denied for pip2.7 install?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I'm on an AWS EC2 instance.
Both Python 2.6 & Python 2.7 are installed.

My PYTHONPATH points to 2.7.
I want to install the mechanize module.

```
sudo pip install mechanize
```

puts it in Python 2.6  :(

So I tried:

```
sudo pip2.7 install mechanize
```

> > sudo: pip2.7: command not found

How can I install mechanize?

Comment: Have you installed pip itself into Python 2.7, or only into Python 2.6?

Comment: I had not!  But so I just installed it like this, this is correct?  -- sudo easy_install-2.7 pip -- and I logged out & logged back in and still get sudo pip2.7 command not found

Answer (score 2):

I would setup a pyvenv installation of python.

This will give you full control over the python environment - plus if you ever mess it up - your default system version of python is not effected.

To do this

```
cd ~
pyvenv  py27
source py27/bin/activate
pip install --upgrade pip
```

And for mechanize

```
 pip install mechanize
```

Answer (score 0):

Though is a little messy, this worked:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/pip2.7 install mechanize
```